# Building an Ios application to track the exact location of the devices within a building

Tags: ios, software-design

i am planning to build  an ios application in which system can  locate the device position with  time being for specific place only within a building.. Such as when student entered  into the school and if the student has attended the certain lecture or  not and if has then for how long he/she has been on that certain class room? However, i  don't have the clear idea  about what is the best way to implement device locator and  how the data is achieved from the device..i have just starting list out the features and design  server side structure  and it would be much more better to have clear picture of those things. So, can you guys please suggest me something better or some source where i gain detailed idea about that? thanks in advance.

Comment: ios uses Swift, not java

Comment: See if this can give you some pointers http://www.code4app.net/ios/Draw-route-onto-indoor-map-using-A-*-algorithm/5270be006803faf773000000. Its for mapping a route within a building but it must be in the same ballpark was what you want to do.

Comment: well java is for server side ......

Comment: @SausageMachine  that link is dead i suppose....

Comment: Stack overflow is automatically deleting parts of the url. Very annoying. Add www to the front of it.

Comment: Also, might the rooms be able to contain beacons? If so you could use them. Read about beacons in iOS

Comment: Thanks alot  @SausageMachine.. Thats what i was searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with MMR. You want use iBeacons, and Apple's Core Location framework.

You'd put a beacon at each location you want to monitor.

You set up "beacon regions" and the system notifies your app when the user enters or exits one of those regions.

On challenge you will face is that the system only allows an app to monitor at most 20 regions at a time. There are ways to deal with this, but it takes deep understanding of how beacon regions work and some creative work.

I am working on an app for a client right now that makes heavy use of beacon regions and is able to track a nearly unlimited number of beacons.

Answer (score 1):

Google for iBeacon. It seems to be a perfect fit for the use-cases listed by you.
Also refer to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/) for Apple documentation on iBeacon.